# is there a way in python that can I merge two arrays (1d/2d/3d) and replacing specific elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, merge

*Simple case*-
I have two arrays:
`x1 = np.arange(1,10)` and `x2 = np.array([0,0,4,0,0,5,0,0,0])`

I would like to merge or combine these two arrays such that the `0` in `x2` will be replaced with values in `x1` and the non-zero elements of `x2`  remains. `NumPy.union1d` seems to do this union. But I **don't** want it sorted/ordered.

Then

*Actual case-*
I would then like to perform this on multi-dimensional arrays, eg: `x.shape=(xx,yy,zz)`. Both array objects will have the same shape. `x.shape = y.shape`

Is this possible or should I try something with masked arrays `NumPy.ma`?

---------------------------Example-----------------------------

```
k_angle = khan(_angle)
e_angle = emss(_angle)

_angle.shape = (3647, 16)
e_angle.shape = (2394, 3647, 16)
k_angle.shape = (2394, 3647, 16)
```

_angle contains a list of values 0 - 180 degrees, if angle < 5 it should only use one function `khan` anything else is `emss` function.
Any value larger than **5** for `khan` becomes **0**. While `emss` works for all values.

*Attempt 1:* I tried splitting the angle values but recombining them proved tricky

```
khan = bm.Khans_beam_model(freq=f, theta=None)
emss = bm.emss_beam_model(f=f)

test = np.array([[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8], [9,10,11]])

gt_idx = test > 5
le_idx = test <= 5
# then update the array
test[gt_idx] = khan(test[gt_idx])
test[le_idx] = emss(test[le_idx])
```

But this gets an error `TypeError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 2 dimensions`

`khan` and `emss` are `lambda' functions

So I thought it would easier to execute `khan` and `emss` and then merge after the fact.

I applied the simple case above to help ease the question.

Comment: Can you please post your code endeavors and provide a minimal reproducible example with actual and expected results?

Comment: @marcelh It is a little challenging to do a reproducible example, but I'll try and redo my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `np.where(boolean_mask, value_if_true, value_otherwise)` function should be sufficient as long as `x1` and `x2` are the same shape.

Here, you could use `np.where(x2, x2, x1)` where the condition is simply `x2`, which means that truthy values (non-zero) will be preserved and falsy values will be replaced by the corresponding values in `x1`. In general, any boolean mask will work as a condition, and it is better to be explicit here: `np.where(x2 == 0, x1, x2)`.

### 1D

```py
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x1 = np.arange(1, 10)

In [3]: x2 = np.array([0,0,4,0,0,5,0,0,0])

In [4]: np.where(x2 == 0, x1, x2)
Out[4]: array([1, 2, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9])
```

### 2D

```py
In [5]: x1 = x1.reshape(3, 3)

In [6]: x2 = x2.reshape(3, 3)

In [7]: x1
Out[7]:
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [8]: x2
Out[8]:
array([[0, 0, 4],
       [0, 0, 5],
       [0, 0, 0]])

In [9]: np.where(x2 == 0, x1, x2)
Out[9]:
array([[1, 2, 4],
       [4, 5, 5],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

### 3D

```py
In [10]: x1 = np.random.randint(1, 9, (2, 3, 3))

In [11]: x2 = np.random.choice((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 99), (2, 3, 3))

In [12]: x1
Out[12]:
array([[[3, 7, 4],
        [1, 4, 3],
        [7, 4, 3]],

       [[5, 7, 1],
        [5, 7, 6],
        [1, 8, 8]]])

In [13]: x2
Out[13]:
array([[[ 0, 99, 99],
        [ 0, 99,  0],
        [ 0, 99,  0]],

       [[99,  0,  0],
        [ 0,  0, 99],
        [ 0, 99,  0]]])

In [14]: np.where(x2 == 0, x1, x2)
Out[14]:
array([[[ 3, 99, 99],
        [ 1, 99,  3],
        [ 7, 99,  3]],

       [[99,  7,  1],
        [ 5,  7, 99],
        [ 1, 99,  8]]])
```

Comment: thank you for this and for showing a new trick with the np.where function

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.